# How to resize textbox and get dimensions inside div element using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, resize, dimensions

I have a div element which can be draggable and I have a textbox inside that div element and when I drag the div element automatically the textbox size should increase along with the div.And I need to get the textbox X and Y positions so how do I do that?

This is what I have now:

http://jsfiddle.net/wWFpP/3/

Here is my ode:

```
   <div class="demo">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
```

This is my script for dragging:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('.demo')
        .draggable()
        .resizable();
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: JSFiddle is a great tool, but it is generally recommended that you paste relevant code in your question so that if your external link is ever inaccessible later, future visitors can still get some grasp on both the problem and the solution.

Comment: You might be able to solve this by looking at jQuery UI.

Comment: @ Kiley Naro Yes I thought that but it will be clear for the one who better understands than what I mention here.Anyways I have updated my code.

Comment: @user944919 The edit you just made is great. This way SO doesn't have to rely on JSFiddle to be complete! Anyway, +1 because this is something I'm curious about as well.

Comment: Thank you so much:) and I am too eager to develop something which is very interesting and much more to learn from you'll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `textarea` should be specified in terms of rows and columns, according to the specs, but you can still style them with CSS:

```
#TextBox1
{
    width: 100%; height: 100%; /* make the element resize */
}
.demo
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 5px 10px 20px 4px; /* updated padding to make things look better */
    background-color: #ff8811;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 300px;
}
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zTPvn/2/). Tested in Firefox, Chrome.

Also, if you need to get the X and Y coordinates, draggable has a `stop` method which you can bind to:

```
$('.demo')
    .draggable({ stop: function(event, ui) {
        //get the textarea element and it's coordinates
        var txt = $(this).find('textarea:first');
        var x = txt.offset().left;
        var y = txt.offset().top;
        alert('(' + x + ', ' + y +')');
    } })
    .resizable();
```

Comment: Updated my answer to make the height adjust as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/gmrcn/

**Edit:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gmrcn/2/

```
#TextBox1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /* edit: fixed @ comment */
}
```

Comment: Yes the same which has been done above by "wsanville" and I need to increase it's height too.Anyways thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thanks once again and how I get the dimensions(ie.. X and Y positions)for the textbox?

Comment: I don't know for sure. Try `$('.demo').style.pixelHeight;` and `$('.demo').style.pixelWidth;`