# jQuery-UI resizable, resizing all child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div that I want to scale. I am using the jQuery-UI resizable option for this, but it isnt resizing the children, why?

This is the code I use to instantiate it:

```
$(this).resizable({
    alsoResize: $(this).find('*'),
});
```

The code is deep inside an app so I created a fiddle that should contain the important parts:
http://jsfiddle.net/EnK4R/6/

This works with the image tag: http://jsfiddle.net/EnK4R/12/ I just cant figure out why the '*' selector wont work

Comment: Can you please include the HTML

Comment: you try using width and height as 100% in all the children elements.

Comment: This is what I have asked previously and worked.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907136/how-to-resize-textbox-and-get-dimensions-inside-div-element-using-jquery may be it will be useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go. this doesnt seem to resize whole document, checkout the fiddle at bottom

```
var init = function(){
    $(this).resizable({
        alsoResize: '#'+$(this).attr('id')+' *'
    });
}

init.call($('#window'));
```

this keeps the code almost as short as yours, and  it will work with what ever gets chucked into the init call. enjoy  :)

http://jsfiddle.net/EnK4R/4/

Comment: what if there is no id though?

Comment: well you put in #window so there is an id?

Comment: also, the text isnt resizing...why?

Comment: that would resize all instances of the class which is the problem

Comment: so why cant you use an unique ID?? and its resizing the P element, not the font-size

Comment: I would rather go with a generic solution if I can

Comment: dont think you can use a dom object as a selector inside things like that. you could try something silly like this http://jsfiddle.net/EnK4R/11/

Comment: the docs say that the type of alsoResize is: "Selector, jQuery, Element". I just dont exactly know what they mean by jQuery

Comment: Add 'overflow:hidden' to .window class

Answer (score 0):

first of all fix the window class selector: change it from `.window` to `#window`. And use selector string for `alsoResize` option:

```
$('#window').resizable({
    alsoResize: '#window *'
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/EnK4R/

Comment: doesnt work from within an init function because I dont have a global identifier: http://jsfiddle.net/EnK4R/2/ The selector '*' resizes the whole document